# QTableWidget select multiple cells permanently identical to Ctrl + MouseClick

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, selection, qtablewidget

Very simple question and hopefully very simple answer.

I have a `QTableWidget` and want to select multiple cells by a simple mouse click, so that I can select some of them all at once. Normally it can be done by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click, which works fine. But due to better usability I would like to change that behaviour!

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can look at `QAbstractItemView::setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SelectionMode)` and `QAbstractItemView::SelectionBehavior`.

Comment: @zarathustra Please post your solution as your own answer as soon as you can. You can then delete your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @vahancho, I solved the "problem"..

Here's the solution:

`tableWidget.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)`

Possible Parameters are:

```
SingleSelection, MultiSelection, ExtendedSelection, ContiguousSelection
```

And [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum) for each.

I hope I can help anyone searching for this solution!